# Session in php expires on browser close?

Tags: php, session

I wrote code in PHP and when I close the browser the session expires and I have to login every time I open the browser, I want to expire the session only when the user press logout button.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your [`session.cookie_lifetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) value in your php.ini configuration. This value represents the lifetime of your session cookie in seconds. By default it is 0, which destroys the cookie upon browser close.